# RabbitTemplate.invoke(OperationsCallBack) is not throwing exceptions when messages are nacked/returned/timeout

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I am using below code to waiting for confirms(ack/nack/returns/timeout) on the same channel.

[image]
[image]

I am sending the incorrect routingKey so rabbitMq should throw an exception as per the below api documentation. But I am not getting an exception from the api.

[image]

We are using timeout for waitForConfirmsOrDie as(60 seconds)
Can someone please suggest if my expectation from the api is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not intuitive, but returned messages do not generate a nack; a positive ack is received after the returned message. Nacks only result from a broker bug, or a queue that has a size limit with the overflow behavior set to `reject-publish`.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html

> For unroutable messages, the broker will issue a confirm once the exchange verifies a message won't route to any queue (returns an empty list of queues). If the message is also published as mandatory, the basic.return is sent to the client before basic.ack.

With [correlated confirms](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#template-confirms) (not simple confirms), you can check whether the message was returned by looking at the correlation data after the ack is received.

> In addition, when both confirms and returns are enabled, the CorrelationData is populated with the returned message, as long as the CorrelationData has a unique id; this is always the case, by default, starting with version 2.3. It is guaranteed that the return message is set before the future is set with the ack.

Comment: Hi Gary, is it always the case that for a returned message, return call back is called prior to confirmCallBack irrespective of the way the messages were submitted to rabbit (waitForConfirmsOrDie (sync) / asynchronously)

Comment: I have  setup callbacks on rabbitTemplate in PostConstruct , for template.invoke I also tried passing the ack/nack callbakcs but I observed that callbacks in template are getting called instead of the callbacks passed in template.invoke.Can asyncTemplate.convertSendAndReceive be used  as an alternative

Comment: should the correlationData be passed to waitForConfirmsOrDie ? As per spring official doc I correlationData has not been passed

Comment: No; you should not use `simple` confirms with returns; use `correlated` confirms instead; add a `CorrelationData` instance to the `convertAndSend()` and wait on its `Future` instead of calling `waitForConfirmsOrDie()`. Remove the `invoke()` call altogether. Refer to the documentation I pointed you to. When the future is completed, check for a returned message (as well as ack Vs. nack).